Unable to display image in ImageView using Uri
I am writing a program on android studio iguana 2023.2.1 that allows the user to select an image from imagePicker on an android 13.0 device (Pixel_3a_API_34), it the retrieves the image URI in the onActivityResult() function and then when the user is ready it saves said URI to shared preferences.
this is the code that handles the selection of the image
private fun openImagePicker1() {
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.type = "image/*"
        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST)
    }

    // Function to handle result of image picker
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        imgPreview = findViewById(R.id.imgPreview)

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.data != null) {
            photoUri = data.data
            imgPreview.setImageURI(photoUri)
        }
    }

this is the code that saves it to shared Preferences
btnSave.setOnClickListener{
            val selectedHour = spnrTime.hour
            val selectedMinute = spnrTime.minute
            val selectedTime = String.format("%02d:%02d", selectedHour, selectedMinute)

            val selectedMonth = datePicker.month + 1
            val day = datePicker.dayOfMonth
            val selectedYear = datePicker.year
            val selectedDate = String.format("%02d/%02d", day, selectedMonth, selectedYear)


            // Concatenate all the details into a single string
            val logEntry = "${details[0]},${details[2]},${details[3]},$selectedTime,$selectedDate,${photoUri.toString()}"

            // Save the updated log data back to SharedPreferences
            val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
            editor.putString("Log_${System.currentTimeMillis()}", logEntry)
            editor.apply()

            Toast.makeText(this, "Session logged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            finish()
        }

i then go to the page where i need to be able to view said image. on this page i keep running into the same error
                                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Calling uid ( 10193 ) does not have permission to access picker uri: content://media/picker/0/com.android.providers.media.photopicker/media/1000000035
. Obviously the actual URI to the image changes but you get the general idea.
this is the code that handles reloading the image at the moment (which doesnt work)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_log)

        //declare elements on screen
        backButton = findViewById(R.id.back_button)
        txtName = findViewById(R.id.ActivityName)
        txtCategory = findViewById(R.id.CategoryName)
        txtTime = findViewById(R.id.TimeOnTask)
        LogPhoto = findViewById(R.id.LogPhoto)

        val activityData = intent.getStringExtra("activityData")
        val logData = intent.getStringExtra("logData")

        val activityList = formatActivities(activityData)
        val logList = formatLogs(logData)
        val logTime = formatSharedPref(logData)

        txtName.setText(activityList[0])
        txtCategory.setText(activityList[2])

        txtTime.setText(logTime)

        val logImageURI = Uri.parse(logList[5])

        LogPhoto.setImageURI(logImageURI)



        backButton.setOnClickListener{
            finish()
        }

    }

Any and all help would be appreciated at this point
I have treid a handful of different solutions with which none have worked or im too stupid to figure how to get them to work. i will list thos which i can remember down below
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_log)

        // Request runtime permission if not granted
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), REQUEST_CODE)
        } else {
            loadLogData()
        }

        // Declare elements on screen
        backButton = findViewById(R.id.back_button)
        txtName = findViewById(R.id.ActivityName)
        txtCategory = findViewById(R.id.CategoryName)
        txtTime = findViewById(R.id.TimeOnTask)
        LogPhoto = findViewById(R.id.LogPhoto)

        backButton.setOnClickListener {
            finish()
        }
    }

    private fun loadLogData() {
        val activityData = intent.getStringExtra("activityData")
        val logData = intent.getStringExtra("logData")

        val activityList = formatActivities(activityData)
        val logList = formatLogs(logData)
        val logTime = formatSharedPref(logData)

        txtName.text = activityList.getOrElse(0) { "" }
        txtCategory.text = activityList.getOrElse(2) { "" }
        txtTime.text = logTime

        val logImageUriString = logList.getOrElse(5) { "" }

        try {
            val logImageUri = Uri.parse(logImageUriString)
            Log.d("ViewLog", "Log Image URI: $logImageUriString")
            LogPhoto.setImageURI(logImageUri)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("ViewLog", "Error loading image: ${e.message}")
            // Handle the case where the app doesn't have permission to access the URI
            // For example, display a placeholder image or show an error message
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val REQUEST_CODE = 100 // Define your request code
    }

i was hoping this one would work as it says its an issue with permissions and this should've dealt with the permissions but instead if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { returned as undefined
i also tried the above fix using a slightly different approach
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), REQUEST_CODE)
}

